# Resistor technologies that guarantee failure mode of OPEN and not short--need docs to prove

Tags: resistors, failure

From chats with several resistor manufacturers, it seems that there's a consensus that certain resistor technologies at high impedance ~120Kohm or more will always open and never short. **Does anyone have documentation that reinforces this "fact"?** Any ideas?

Comment: Look into carbon composition (bulk, not film) resistors. Overhauling old vacuum tube gear, the hotter running ones tend to be 130% or more of rated value. Don't have specific documentation, sorry,  just saying that's where I'd start looking.

Comment: Ohmcraft has a line of printed resistors that can withstand pretty surprising pulses.

http://www.ohmcraft.com/uploads/WP_SuperiorPulseResistorCapability.pdf

You might consider giving them a ring and seeing if they can guarantee fail-open.

Answer (score 3):

You might be looking for *fusible resistors*.  They are designed specifically for to *open* when overloaded. There's a helpful discussion on the [EEVblog forum](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/beginners/what-is-a-fuse-resistor/).

Examples of fusible resistors are those from [Vishay](http://www.vishay.com/resistors-linear/fusible/) and [TE](http://www.te.com/catalog/feat/en/s/26890).

Comment: Fusible resistors and chip fuses seem to be limted to very low ohmic values and we need ~ 60K-120K ohm.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use the fusible resistor in series with the 60k-120k resistor that you need?  So what if the 60k fails short, the fusible resistor will open.

Answer (score 2):

> Resistor technologies that guarantee failure mode of OPEN and not
>   short--need docs to prove

I think these resistor types probably fit the bill: -

[image]

If you need to research others - there are several brands of wire wound resistors that are regarded as fail-safe when it comes to the design of zener barriers for use in potantially explosive atmospheres.

[Here](http://www.rutronik.co.uk/news+M5bbd9450d18.html) are some other types - try searching "approved safety resistor"

Comment: Explored this with TT on a conf call this morning and all agreed that it will likely fit the bill. But the issue remains how to convince UL that a failure that ends up as a short is impossible.  Safety resistors seem to have very low ohmic values and we need ~ 60K-120K ohm.

Comment: Have you tried asking UL what they would consider appropriate?

Comment: Yes, trying to. They are being difficult. Hence looking for some concrete docs. Perhaps the better angle is the single-point of failure route raised by @spehro (maybe I need to hire someone to find something that helps in UL916?)

Answer (score 1):

Well, certainly avoid carbon film resistors!

I don't think it is true. I think that the most likely candidate (metal film resistors) have been shown to drop in resistance due to [pulse load](http://www.vishay.com/marcom/sc/newsletters/distributors/04q3/europe/latest_news_3.html) damage.

> > Damage Caused By Pulse Loads
>
> More than 80% of the failures attributable to pulse load damage,
>   equivalent to 0.04 ppm overall, displayed helical shorts within the
>   device, causing a large fall in resistive value. A further small
>   number of failures, contributing around 0.01 ppm, displayed a positive
>   change in resistance. These failures arise from irregularities in the
>   ceramic surface that compromise the sputtering process and the
>   formation of the resistive film. Harsh pulses can then cause local hot
>   spots that gradually destroy the sputtered resistive layers and the
>   neighbouring resistive film.

For safety-critical applications you may have to put two resistors in series.

Edit:-
Could you use a resistor in series with an approved Y-rated capacitor?

I also note that sometimes UL-listed ESD wrist straps use two resistors in series
(one at each end). That's a clear example where a resistor failed short could expose someone to severe risk of electrical shock.

Comment: From what I've understood, placing even 4 resistors in series will not guarantee an open failure instead of a short.  In other words, there could be a cascading failure that will result in all resistors in series shorting.  So we're back to the original question: assurance that failure will result in an open and not a short.

Comment: I mentioned it because it does seem to satisfy UL requirements for some applications- no single point failure can cause a hazard. There are UL recognized fusible resistors, but not 100K ohms AFAIK.

Comment: Funny -- that's been my argument as well.  Seems like the no single point of failure argument can fly for much more safety-critical applications, but no for ours!? This is actually for a wall switch, filed under ENERGY MANAGEMENT EQUIPMENT - UL 916. Nothing in the standard seems to deal with single point failure, etc.

Comment: The particular piece of equipment I have in mind could easily completely take out a single-family dwelling (WMD anyone?).

Comment: Is there a UL doc that describes this single-point of failure point, or is it specific to each standard. UL916 doesn't seem to talk about this either way.

Comment: I don't know if they were that prescriptive, just know that it passed.